# Inline html style fine in Firefox, not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, stylesheet

This is interesting.  The attached very simple code gives nice 'background highlighted' text in Firefox, but displays no highlighting in IE7 (and possibly others, not yet tested).

The use of such inline elements is important because I'm using them in a grid to highlight important words etc.

Test.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
This is <hlr>a test</hlr> of the <hlr>highlighting</hlr>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.css

```
/*RED Highlighted text.*/
hlr
{
    background-color: #FF5555;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:100%;
}
```

Bizarre!  Any thoughts on how to remedy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hlr is invalid markup. Try this instead:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
This is <span class='hlr'>a test</span> of the <span class='hlr'>highlighting</span>
</body>
</html>
```

then:

```
/*RED Highlighted text.*/
.hlr
{
    background-color: #FF5555;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks mate, that did the trick perfectly!  A strange and interesting effect indeed.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Glinkot why didn't you accept the answer if this worked for you??.

Comment: Am going to but it told me I had to wait 4 more minutes for some reason :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `hlr` element in HTML. Internet Explorer doesn't make elements it doesn't recognise available to it's CSS selector engine.

The solution is to **write HTML, don't make up your own elements**. You should probably be using `<em>` or `<strong>` instead, possibly with a class to distinguish them from other forms of emphasis.

You can also force new elements to be recognised by the selector engine with `document.createElement('element_name')`, but adding a JS dependancy isn't a great idea and doesn't resolve the issue that no browser will know what semantics to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David.  That sounds like it would work though referring to a custom style via the class reference/span tag Jhourlad mentioned did work like a charm.  Thanks for your response mate.

Comment: @conqenator: You hurt my feeling. Just kidding :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the below XHTML doctype too..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  It didn't end up being a dependency but standards compliance is always a good scheme.